# How to determine a capacitor value across a switch carrying DC

Tags: capacitor, switches, contact

The tiny rocker switches I'm using in a current project are supposedly good for 3A DC, which is at least 2X what I'd expect to draw worst case. It is supplied from a hefty Li-ION battery source nominally 12V, and these are cheaply made switches. So I'd like to include a capacitor across the switch to prevent some of the likely arcing when the switch is opened, and hopefully give the contacts better longevity. Is that reasoning sound and if so, how would you approximate a reasonable value for the cap?

Comment: wouldn't a capacitor increase inrush current? are you looking for an inrush protection device? There are passive and active alternatives for this.

Comment: Furthermore, a charged cap across the switch, the instant the switch is closed, discharges through the switch. This behavior may negate any benefit from it being there when the switch is opened.

Comment: My thinking though is that arcing is more destructive to contacts then a very brief added inrush current. But that added inrush current is one reason not to overdo it with so much capacitance that I'd create a new problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](https://www.idec.com/language/english/AppNotes/Relays/contact_circuit_protection.pdf) has several suggestions to provide arc suppression for pushbutton (or relay) contacts controlling a load.

This and other pages I looked at all use a resistor in series with the capacitor to limit inrush current.  The examples are shown for inductive loads, but I would think the RC solution (known as a [snubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber#RC_snubbers)) would work for restrictive loads as well (whereas the diode suppression across a relay coil is specifically designed for inductive loads).

[image]

The suggested values of R and C from the page I linked to above are 0.5Ω to 1Ω per 1V of contact voltage, and 0.5 µF to 1 µF per 1A of contact current, although I have [also seen](http://www.emcuk.co.uk/awareness/Pages/MitigationTechniques/Design/SuppressArcSpark.htm) values of 100 Ω and 100 nF used.

Comment: Thanks, and that series resistor makes perfect sense. I also appreciate the general "rule of thumb" you offered. I'd get lost in the probably 2 pages of math needed to really explain how to actually calculate the values. I see where for inductive loads its a more critical, but I'm pretty sure old cheap welding boxes had nothing but series resistance, so I'm sure you can strike an arc with just DC. Anyway, this hopefully will help my cheap switches last longer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.electrocube.com/resistor-capacitor-networks/#RCNSB?utm_source=electrocube-eblast&utm_medium=constant-contact-email&utm_content=rcnetwork-substitution-box&utm_campaign=may-june-next-step-industry-fitness

These guys recommend trial and error (and a good scope).

Comment: I wouldn't risk a good scope on an inductive switched load. A bad one, maybe!

Comment: @Transistor you can always add a low-capacitance transient suppressor.

Answer (score 0):

A good reference to the switch arcing is older fashion breaker points in a car engine ignition system. Once called condenser.The condenser will reduce arcing for longer life of contacts as they open repeated thousands of times per minute dependent on RPM,s. I also am looking for the formula to calculate capacitance! For now I just used a cap out of a space heater for arc prevention at 120 volts, 15 amp AC. So far no problems after several years. My conclusions the cap provides some protection.

Answer (score 0):

The R value is simple; it wants to be chosen to comfortably cover any possible current which may be flowing through the switch when it opens. So R=V/I...    Plug in the V and the I you expect, and double the result for a safety factor.

The C value depends what circuit is being driven. You want to be sure the capacitor can absorb all the inductive stored energy, while staying below the rated voltage. For simple resistive loads, your only stored energy is in cable inductance, so a few nanofarads will be enough.

So for a 10 A switch switching 250 V, R=12 ohms, C = 100 nF should be fine.